# How to create project with specific region

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create new firebase project with specific region (Asia-South 1). Whenever I create, it takes eur3 (europe-west) as default and there is no option to select from firebase console.

I tried to create project from GCP and crated firestore in desired region. But now I can not see that project in Firebase console.

The bottom line is to create firebase project with default region as Asia-South 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a screen capture to show the process in the Firebase Console.
Even if you set a different region when creating your whole **Firebase** project, you will still be able to select a region for your **Cloud Firestore** project:

[image]

The warning shows you that you can **only set your location once**. If you already initialized Cloud Firestore in your project, you will have to create a new project to change your location.

Comment: Thank you. However after some time I can add project from GCP by clicking [+] add project and selecting project name which was there in GCP.